# Get Json Object in Asp.net Controller with no need to create a classe

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

can i retrieve an json object in a asp.net mvc controller?

Here's my ajax request

```
// get form values
var nameValue = $("#name").val();
var ageValue = $("#age").val();

// json object
var person = {

    name: nameValue,
    age: ageValue
};


        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/GetData',
            type: 'POST',
            data:{userObj: person},
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Erro :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + "| " + textStatus + "| " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

And here's my asp.net MVC controller method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public String GetData(dynamic userObj)
        {
            dynamic person = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(userObj);
            return userObj.name; // It didn't work
        }
```

I want to retrieve this object in my controller, and use it as userObj.name, userObj.age like a json object inside C# with no need to create a C# class with same parameters to this.

Is there some way?

Answer (score 1):

You variable `person` is already the object you need to send to the controller so you ajax function should be

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', // don't hard code your url's
    type: 'POST',
    data: person, // change this
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        alert(data);
    },
```

and then you controller method should be

```
[HttpPost]
public String GetData(Person userObj)
```

where `Person` is

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  pubic int Age { get; set; }
}
```

When you post the data, the value of `userObj` will be correctly bound with the values of `nameValue` and `ageValue`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your tips Stephen, it works fine, but is there some way to retrieve this data with no need to create a Person class in C#?

Comment: You can use parameters for each value - public String GetData(string Name, int Age)` (but why would you want to do that?)

Comment: Like you said, it is not the best way use parameters for each value. I'm looking for some way to use an Object without have the same object in C# code. Like PHP you can receive an entire object via POST and i don't need to have the same object in PHP code, i just retrieve it and save in a variable or array. But i think it is not possible in C#